# How to set JWT type in JWT Header

Tags: json, jersey, jwt, jax-rs

Not able to set the JWT token typ in token header.

This is for making secure API's which i have already developed in JAX-RS. Basically i have generating a token by Jwts.builder() method, and in return i am getting token in APPLICATION_JSON, ant i paste this token at https://jwt.io/ Debugger. So i got to know that there is no token type specified token header,there is only {
  "alg": "HS512"
}
 Maybe this could be a reason that i cannot access secured API's. When i try to access secured API's then i got "Signed Claims JWSs are not supported" exception.

AuthenticationService.java

```
private String issueToken(String login, String password) {

        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now().plusMinutes(10L);
        Instant instant = now.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
        Date jwtExpiry = Date.from(instant);

        String jwtToken = Jwts.builder().setSubject(login).setIssuer("XYZ").setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .setExpiration(jwtExpiry).signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, "secretKey").compact();
        return jwtToken;
}

public class JWTTokenNeededFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter 
{
    public static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(JWTTokenNeededFilter.class);

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        String token = requestContext.getHeaderString("userToken");
        if (token == null) {
            requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build());
        }

        try {
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey("secretKey").parseClaimsJwt(token);

            logger.info("Valid Token " + token);

        } catch (ExpiredJwtException expiredJwtException) {
            logger.info("Token Expires " + expiredJwtException);
            requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build());
        }

        catch (Exception exception) {
            logger.info("Exceptioin " + exception);
            requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build());
        }
    }
}
```

I am expecting token header like this

> {
>     "alg": "HS512",
>     "typ": "JWT"
>   }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set using header as explained here : https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt/issues/174

```
Header header = Jwts.header();
header.setType("JWT");
```

Then set header to builder (I haven't compiled the code)

```
private String issueToken(String login, String password) {

    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now().plusMinutes(10L);
    Instant instant = now.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
    Date jwtExpiry = Date.from(instant);

    Header header = Jwts.header();
    header.setType("JWT");
    //set additional headers
    String jwtToken = 
       Jwts.builder().setHeader((Map<String, Object>) 
        header).setSubject(login).setIssuer("XYZ").setIssuedAt(new 
        Date())
            .setExpiration(jwtExpiry).signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, 
          "secretKey").compact();
    return jwtToken;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can set the header just using the `setHeaderParam("typ","JWT")` jwt builder method.
https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt#header-parameters

```
 String token = Jwts.builder()
                    .setHeaderParam("typ","JWT")
                    .setSubject(user.getUserId().toString())
                    .claim("Roles",authResult.getAuthorities())
                    .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                    .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+EXPIRATION_TIME))
                    .signWith(Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(key))
                    .compact();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Header.JWT_TYPE` static field in Header interface. This is more cleanable and avoid boilerplate code: For example:

```
 private static String generateToken() {
        return Jwts.builder()
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, secretKey)
                .setHeaderParam("typ", Header.JWT_TYPE)
                .compact();
    }
and output which you want:
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "HS256"
}
```